# ASP.NET MVC 3, Action Filters, and Autofac Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, autofac, action-filter

On **ASP.NET MVC 2** I have an `ActionFilterAttribute` called `[Transaction]` that starts an NHibernate transaction before executing the action and commits or rolls it back afterward, depending on whether or not an exception was thrown. The `ISession` instance is `HttpRequestScoped()` and injected by [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/). It looks like this and works great:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public sealed class TransactionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private ITransaction transaction;

    public TransactionAttribute()
    {
        this.Order = 0;
    }

    public ISession Session
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(
        ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (this.Session != null && this.transaction != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (this.transaction.IsActive)
                {
                    if (filterContext.Exception == null)
                    {
                        this.transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.transaction.Rollback();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                this.transaction.Dispose();
                this.transaction = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(
        ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (this.Session != null)
        {
            this.transaction = this.Session.BeginTransaction();
        }
    }
}
```

Fantastic. [Seems to be a common pattern.](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2009/09/03/asp-net-mvc-transaction-attribute-using-nhibernate.aspx)

In the **ASP.NET MVC 3** notes, I see this little blurb under "Breaking Changes" (emphasis mine):

> In previous versions of ASP.NET MVC, *action filters were created per request* except in a few cases. This behavior was never a guaranteed behavior but merely an implementation detail and the contract for filters was to consider them stateless. In ASP.NET MVC 3, filters are *cached more aggressively*. Therefore, any custom action filters which improperly store instance state might be broken.

Oops.

- Does this mean I'm hosed if I upgrade to MVC 3?
- If action filters are no longer instanced per request, how will we get request-scoped dependencies into our action filters?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just asked a similar question on google forums.
Here is the link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/autofac/a0qqp2b3WA8

I got the answer:

```
builder.RegisterType<ExtensibleActionInvoker>().As<IActionInvoker>();


builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).InjectActionInvoker();
```

Then you can use property injection in your attributes.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the release note comment applies to the default setup in MVC -- but IoC containers override this to provide their own behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

Oh yuck.... Nicholas, you might need to store your ISession and Transaction in HttpContext.Items, which you should be able to get to via the ActionExecutedContext/ActionExecutingContext (perhaps setting it in the OnActionExecuting event handler), instead of keeping them in instance members.  Either that, or you could call a ServiceLocator inside your filter to grab them for you (also yuck).

Now I have to go look through my MVC 3 code and see if I have any similar problems myself!